# Python ImportError when trying to import a module in different path

Tags: python

I'm new in python programming and i've got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ultrasonicExample.py", line 7, in ?
    from concretesensor.hcsr04 import HCSR04
ImportError: No module named concretesensor.hcsr04
```

here's my app structure:

```
sensorPy/
        src/                                       
            abstractclass/                  
                  __init__.py
                 ultrasonicSensor.py
              ...
          concretesensor/                 
                  __init__.py
                  hcsr04.py
              ...
          examples/                 
                  __init__.py
                  ultrasonicExample.py
```

my `__init__.py` under abstractclass:

```
from abstractclass.ultrasonicSensor import UltrasonicSensor
```

my `__init__.py` under concretesensor:

```
from concretesensor.hcsr04 import HCSR04
```

I also cheched my sys.path:

```
>>> import sys
>>> from pprint import pprint as p
>>> p(sys.path)
['',
 ...
 '/home/pi/Documents/sensorPy/src',
...
 ]
>>>
```

im `ultrasonicExample.py` I do:

```
from concretesensor.hcsr04 import HCSR04
```

in `hcsr04.py` I do:

```
from abstractclass.ultrasonicSensor import UltrasonicSensor
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `__init__.py`s should just contain e.g. `from ultrasonicSensor import UltrasonicSensor`.

Comment: Do `export PYTHONPATH='/home/pi/Documents/sensorPy/src'` and then run your code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `concretesensor` must in `PYTHONPATH` [variable](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH). Alternate (and better) way is add your path to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/my/path")
```

Try insert relative path to `sys.path` ([read about](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html))

```
sys.path.append("../..") #root of application
```

and write `__init__.py` in root application directory.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'll try this when I come home. Just some more doubts:
 should I put `code` sys.path.append("../..") inside my __init__.py (under concretesensor) ? I thought It was not necessary, since when I do :
pprint(sys.path)   it returns me '/home/pi/Documents/sensorPy/src'. 
and when you say "write __init__.py in root application directory." it means under src folder or under sensorPy folder?

Comment: Situate your code to `PYTHONPATH` e.g. `site-package` and use it everywhere without `sys.path.append`.